# SonarQube: build breaker not working anymore after adding branch

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 4.0, Build Breaker plugin 1.1 and Issue Report plugin 1.1. They were working fine in the past. Recently I have to add branch information to my project using -Dsonar.branch parameter, and after that Build Breaker plugin does not work anymore. Every time it complains threshold reached and build failed, but I can see nothing related to Alerts (new blocker issue should not be found) I set for the project in issue report.

I already deleted the original project without branch information in SonarQube, and even restart the SonarQube server, but the issue still exists. Since Build Breaker plugin does not output any details of the violations, and I cannot find violations in issue report generated, I have no idea how to proceed now. Maybe try to upgrade to SonarQube 4.3?

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Using the sonar.branch property leads to create a fully new project in SonarQube so are you sure that the expected quality profile (containing your alerts) is really used when analysing this branch ?

Comment: Yes, I already linked the quality profiles to newly created project (with branch extension in their names). What confused me a lot is that issue report does not contain any violations regarding alerts, but build breaker complains violations...

Comment: I tried to change the alerts, and it does impact the build breaker result, but I have no idea why build breaker plugin complains violations (in my case new blocker issue should be zero) even issue report plugin shows no new blocker issue at all. May I know how build breaker plugin evaluate alerts like mine in database level?

Comment: you're talking about the build breaker, the issue report, the sonar.branch property and the fact that you don't have any new blocker issue (are you sure that the alert is defined to work on new blocker issues and not only on blocker issues ?). That's pretty hard to understand your context, could you provide a precise use case ? 1-new project; 2-quality profiles with following alert conditions, 3- ...

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea but after upgrading to Sonar 4.3 the incremental check is working again.